# Promise not fulfilled

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is a basic question. I'm working through a js/node workshop on async programming called promise-it-wont-hurt. I have the following exercise:

```
Create a promise. Have it fulfilled with a value of 'FULFILLED!' in
executor after a delay of 300ms, using setTimeout.

Then, print the contents of the promise after it has been fulfilled by passing
console.log to then.
```

my test.js file contains:

```
var promise = new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {

  setTimeout(() => 'FULFILLED!',300);
});

promise.then((r)=> console.log(r));
```

When I run "node test.js" at the command line , I get no output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this does is return the string `'FULFILLED!'`:

```
() => 'FULFILLED!'
```

But it doesn't return it *to* anywhere.  `setTimeout` certainly doesn't do anything with that result, and neither does the `Promise`.  To fulfill the `Promise` with a value, you have the `fulfill` function provided by the `Promise` itself:

```
() => fulfill('FULFILLED!')
```

(This is more commonly called `resolve`, but it doesn't really matter what you call it as long as it's the first parameter in the function passed to the `Promise` constructor.)

As you can imagine, to reject the `Promise` you'd call the `reject` function similarly.

Comment: So in the function predicate you can indicate the return value of a function f as (f) => {f(value)} - eg ... { .() => fulfill('FULFILLED!') } ?

Comment: @user1592380: I think it's simpler than what you're trying to describe.  A `Promise` object constructor takes a function with two arguments.  The `Promise` itself provides those arguments.  The first is a callback for success, the second is a callback for failure.  Within that overall function you can do whatever you like, which will mostly likely be an asynchronous operation (or more than one).  As long as those callbacks are eventually used, the promise can be awaited.

Answer (score 1):

You never call `fulfill` (which is more idiomatically named `resolve`).

The function you pass to `setTimeout` just *returns* (uselessly because `setTimeout` doesn't care about the return value) a string.

It needs to call `fulfill` with the string as an argument.

```js
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('FULFILLED!')
  }, 300);
});

promise.then((r) => {
  console.log(r)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The setTimeout call back should call `fulfill("FULFILLED!")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use below syntax

```
promise.then(res => {
      console.log("fulfilled");
    }, err => {
      console.log("rejected");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var promise = new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => fulfill('FULFILLED!'), 300);
});

promise.then((r)=> console.log(r));
```

Comment: So in the function predicate you can indicate the return value of a function f as (f) => {f(value)}  - eg  ... { .() => fulfill('FULFILLED!') } ?

Comment: This could be the answer.
https://codepen.io/Universalist/post/predicates-in-javascript